# Redirect Https requests?

Tags: iptables, http, redirection, https

*Being a noob for such considerations, please dont hit me...*

I have redirection from many domains *--to-->* a unique landing page of my server.

This works painlessly for http

**Here is my question : How can I make it work for https ?**

*I added port 443 redirected to 80 in iptables, without success*

*It is maybe completely stupid to ask that, just let me know if it is*

Comment: What command did you use? Also, this is usually a terrible idea.

Comment: @geewee Why is it a terrible idea ? I feel it but Im very unsure why.... #horrible_noob

Comment: @geewee I use something like 'iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i wlan0 -j DNAT -dport 443 --to 192.168.9.2:80'

Comment: Basically @Paul's answer. You have to make sure the server (192.168.9.2) is https-capable.

Comment: Why a -2 ? Is my question badly shaped ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https is a different protocol to http, so simply redirecting to a different port is not going to work unless the server listening on that port understands https.

If you want to respond to https requests, you need an https server.  Once the https session is established you can serve the page.

Comment: thanks for lightening it. Huh... what about apache and https ?

Comment: What is the question?  Yes, apache can serve https.

Comment: I have enabled mod_ssl + default-ssl.conf <== http://www.it-connect.fr/configurer-le-ssl-avec-apache-2%EF%BB%BF/ . Let's see. Thanks

Comment: I installed & configured ssl and I get on my client browser : ssl_error_rx_record_too_long. If i join my server https from itself it works (just telling me my cert is risky, I used the snakeoil default one). if ever you had a quick response 'bout it.